# How do I create a view from the results of a select statement on the same table?

Tags: mysql, database-design

I have a table that has three columns. The id of a material, the family it belongs (there is some kind of grouping), the type of test and the results of that test as a number (1-4). The type of test points to a table with a list of tests and the result is a number. I am trying to create a query/view if appropriate so that I can have a result of a family of materials and for each test a new column with the cell showing the average of that test in all the materials in the family...

I am thinking that since it's for a small project and I know the test (don't think they are going to change but not sure) that I could just add the tests (they are 6 of them) as columns in the table instead of having it as data but it doesn't feel right to me. Also, there could be a chance that a test would be added in the future. At the same time though, adding a column would not be hard and I could just change the code for averages to disregard values to a specific value so I could differentiate from values before a test was added.

So how would I go about doing it and is it a good idea the way I am doing it?

For now what I have is maybe making a select statement for each pair of family/test and then somehow creating a view (is it a virtual table) with the results of those queries.

So if the table is

```
test_result
family_id | material_id | test_id | result
```

The query would be

```
SELECT AVG(result) AS 'TEST'
FROM test_result
WHERE family_id = 'family_id'
  AND test_id = 'test_id;
```

But I am not sure how to proceed or if there is a better way than doing this 6 times and somehow combining the results

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure how much you know about database design.

The question you are asking, about having 6 columns for test_id in one table versus having another table with family_id and test_id as the primary key (unique identifier) is a fundamental one about database design. It has to do with first normal form. You can study up on first normal form, and on data normalization generally, if you choose to.

Here is an oversimplified version, for this case.

There are two big problems with the six columns in one table approach.

The first is this: what happens when they change their minds and add a seventh test? If this never happens, everything is ok. But if not, you have to alter the table by adding another column, and you have to alter any queries that reference the table. If that's only one query in your case, you can manage it.  In cases where there are hundreds of queries that may reference the table, and some of those are in application programs that may require a maintenance cycle to revise the query, this can be a nightmare. That is why database tutorials are full of material that you may not need to learn if this small project is the only one you ever do.

The second is this: what happens when you have to write a query that has to find every occurrence of testid = 4, regardless of which of the six columns the value is stored in? You are going to have to write a query with five OR operators in the WHERE clause. This is tedious, error prone, and runs slow. Again, this may never be a problem.

The generally better approach is to create a third table with family_id and test_id as columns, and maybe result as a third column (I'm not sure what material_id is... is there a material table?)

The first table, families, has the family_id and any data that only depends on the family, like family_name.

The second table, tests, has the test_id and any data that only depends on the test, like test_name.

And the third table contains data that depends on both.

You then write a view that joins all three tables to together,  to make it look the way you want to use it.

I apologize if this covers a lot of concepts you already know. Again,  I couldn't tell from your question.

Comment: No this was very helpful. I know just the basics from when I took a course. I know about normalisation, hence why I asked the question, because I knew that it is better to do that, just wanted a clearer idea why (not the vague feeling in my head, i remember something :) ). However how would I write the view query? This is my real dilemma. It seems that each column in the table I want is the result of a select statement as i mentioned in my original question but how do I join them? Can I do a join in different select statements?